# WScript.Run Command is not working for me

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I am attaching WSCript code below just to execute simple run command but it is showing error

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir"
```

> Error: oShell.run is not recognized as a internal or external command.

Please help me knowing what wrong I did.

Comment: That is interesting, what OS are you running? Could possibly be a permission related issue, but don't quote me never had this problem myself.

Comment: What is the command *(`cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir`)* doing you are trying to run is that `&` expected?

Comment: for & see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php

Comment: Is this part of a `.vbs` file or part of a `.bat` file? Also -- what is `Dir`? A string variable? If so, it belongs outside the quote marks.

Comment: Dir is the 'list directory' command.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Yeah just tried it in a command prompt, thanks.

Comment: @JohnColeman In other words it's part of the `cmd` it first changes directory to `C:\ ` then once that finishes list the file structure with `Dir`.

Comment: I knew what `dir` does at the command prompt but thought that perhaps they were using it a a VBScript variable holding the name of the directory to move to and were confused about how string concatenation works.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that you gave `oShell.run` to the shell. If you save your two lines to a .vbs file and run it with cscript.exe, it will 'work'.

Evidence:

[image: Evidence]

**Update wrt comment:**

If you feed a line to the shell, it tries to map the first word to its list of internal or external commands (taking the path and known extensions into account):

```
DNV35 C:\Documents and Settings\eh
oShell.run pipapo

'oShell.run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: I am not able to run any command with WScript object. Let it be a Run command or SendKeys. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: @user2695448 - because you are not feeding your code to a VBScript interpreter like cscript.exe (wscript.exe) but to a/the shell who tries to map first words to commands.

Comment: @user2695448 VBScript isn't a language to be used directly in a command shell. If you want such a language -- I would suggest learning Windows Powershell . VBScript has its uses but is borderline obsolete.